# Workaround for showing font size > 1000px?

Tags: css, firefox

Firefox [limits font display](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1188579) to a size of 1000px. Users of my application with large displays may need font sizes > 1000px. Anyone aware of a work around?

I've tried using different units (rem, em, %) and changing the body font size in %.

Comment: Use scale? I don't know why you need this.

Comment: My application is a big countdown timer called Big Timer. Its USP is that it's as big as possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use css transforms instead, like:

```
transform:scale(200%,200%);
```

Comment: Of course! To get this to work, I have to use transform:scale(2); though. Thanks!